# JQUery Animation

Tags: jquery, animation

```
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            position:absolute;
            background-color:#abc;
            left:100px;
            width:90px;
            height:90px;
            margin:15px;
            right:15px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="left">&laquo;</button>
    <button id="right">&raquo;</button>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <script>
        $("#right").click(function () {
            $(".block").animate({
                "left": "+=50px"
            }, "slow");
        });

        $("#left").click(function () {
            $(".block").animate({
                "left": "-=50px"
            }, "slow");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The question I have is the significance of "left" in   $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");    I changed to "right" on both  now the block isn't moving or animating now. It only seesm to work when "left".

Comment: Maybe try animating the margins instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe when there is a conflict between `left` and `right`, left is taking precedence.  You really shouldn't be defining both, just one or the other.

Remove `left` from the `css` and then changing to `right` should work.

Answer (score 1):

For one you are defining left, which will hold priority. If you want right to work, remove the left declaration from your css.

Answer (score 0):

right and left both cannot work in relative positioning. You can only make use of one property

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you're using the left absolute positioning. Change it to right and it works.